# XmlSerializer Utf-8 encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding

Consider the code below

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));

  using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
  {
    // Serialize the object, and close the TextWriter.
    serializer.Serialize(writer, invoice);
    writer.Close();
  }
```

No encoding is set on the stream writer by default. Does it default to UTF-8 if you don't set an encoding on the stream writer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, by default `StreamWriter` is created for using UTF-8 without preamble. See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the StreamWriter does default to UTF-8 as mentioned [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.537492.2)